# prevent multiple open .XMAL windows when button pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

guys how can I prevent the opening already open WPF window (without using the user control and not adding in to windows form) when button press event ?

I have following codes, but each time I press the button it will open WPF window according to button pressed amount.

Dose anybody know how to prevent that error
Thank you,

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        win2 v2 = new win2();
        v2.Show();

    }
```

here , when each time i click the above button it will open a window, but when its already open; if I clicked the same button it will open another window instead of focusing to the already open window.

how can I prevent that?
(I'm using C# )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Application.Current.Windows.OfType<win2>().Any())
        {
            win2 v2 = new win2();
            v2.Show();
        }   
    }
```

Application.Current.Windows lists all the currently open windows owned by your program. We can check if any are already open that are of the type `win2`, and if not, then we create a new one.

Comment: im just wondering if i can able to use above code on wpf windows created on blend. will it work. or do i have to use some other code?. can please explain me. thank you

Comment: @RoshiEnd I think this should work for all WPF, but you may have to test it out to be sure :)

Answer (score 1):

```
win2 v2 = null;

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

   if (v2 == null)
    {
       v2 = new win2();
       v2.Show();
    }
    else
       v2.Activate();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Application.Current.Windows` to find all the open windows in your application.

If it contains your `Window` type `Activate` it to bing it into focus, if the collection does not contain your `Window` create a new one

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Application.Current.Windows.OfType<win2>().Any())
    {
        Application.Current.Windows.OfType<win2>().First().Activate();
    }
    else
    {
        new win2().Show();      
    }
}
```